# Possible formulation of function as to speed up calculations in a multiple dependant function

Tags: r

I have the following list and would like to add each element of each sublist to each element of the second list, carring the cummulative sum forward. With one caveat as I move one list forward each time the number of removed elements in that list increases by one. The calculation is very time consuming and would like to know if there is a possible formulation of the last multiple functions as to speed up the function.

```
DF3 <- list( c ( 12 ,35 ,90 ,33 ,51 ) , c (  44 , 3 ,88 ,35 ,51 ) , c(12 ,16  ,6 ,10 ,3 ,12 ,2 ,6 ,9 ,4 ,4 ,51 ,13 ,22 ,51 ) , c( 44 ,3 ,37 ,51 ,35 ,51 ) , c( 12, 16 , 6 ,10 , 3 ,12 , 2 , 6 , 9 , 4 , 4 ,51 ,13 , 8 , 3 , 5 , 6 ,51 ) , c( 12 ,16,  6, 10,  3, 37, 51, 35, 51 ) , c( 12, 16, 16, 3, 37, 51, 35, 51 ))

DF3
[[1]]
12 35 90 33 51 
[[2]]
44 3 88 35 51 
[[3]]
12 16 6 10 3 12 2 6 9 4 4 51 13 22 51 
[[4]]
44  3 37 51 35 51 
[[5]]
12 16 6 10 3 12 2 6 9 4 4 51 13 8 3 5 6 51 
[[6]]
12 16 6 10 3 37 51 35 51 
[[7]]
12 16 16 3 37 51 35 51 

# Obtain the list of elements to add to the prior list of elements sequentially. 

fun <- function (x) tail ( DF3[[x]] , length ( DF3[[x]] ))
S <- lapply ( seq ( length ( DF3 ))[ 1 : ( max (length ( DF3 )))] , fun )[-1]
fun <- function (x) tail (S[[x]] , length( S[[x]])-x)
SS <- c( DF3[[1]][[1]], lapply ( seq ( length ( DF3 )-1), fun ))

# Every result element from previous sum will be added to next list of elements rolling one possition forward for each new list than in the prior list.  

D1  <-  ( SS[[1]] + SS[[2]] ) 
a   <- seq(nrow(expand.grid(SS[[1]]+SS[[2]],SS[[3]])))
fun <- function (x) sum(expand.grid ( SS[[1]] + SS[[2]] , SS[[3]] )[,1][x], expand.grid ( SS[[1]] + SS[[2]] , SS[[3]] )[,2][x] )
D2  <- unlist(lapply (a , fun)) 
b   <- seq(nrow(expand.grid(D2,SS[[4]])))
fun <- function (x) sum(expand.grid (expand.grid(D2,SS[[4]])[,1][x], expand.grid(expand.grid(D2,SS[[4]]))[,2][x] ))
D3  <- unlist(lapply (b , fun)) 
c   <- seq(nrow(expand.grid(D3,SS[[5]])))
fun <- function (x) sum(expand.grid (expand.grid(D3,SS[[5]])[,1][x], expand.grid(expand.grid(D3,SS[[5]]))[,2][x] ))
D4  <- unlist(lapply (c , fun)) 
d   <- seq(nrow(expand.grid(D4,SS[[6]])))
fun <- function (x) sum(expand.grid (expand.grid(D4,SS[[6]])[,1][x], expand.grid(expand.grid(D4,SS[[6]]))[,2][x] ))
D5  <- unlist(lapply (d , fun))
e   <- seq(nrow(expand.grid(D5,SS[[7]])))
fun <- function (x) sum(expand.grid (expand.grid(D5,SS[[7]])[,1][x], expand.grid(expand.grid(D5,SS[[7]]))[,2][x] ))
D6  <- unlist(lapply (d , fun))
```

Is there a way to write the last expresion in a more concise manner and also is there a way to speed up through another formulation as this is extremely slow.

EDIT

From the final result D6 (cs from the answer below). I would like to find out the location index in each of the DF3 lists that when sequentially cumsums to 221.

```
# Taking the answer for the sake of time

f <- function(x, y) rep(x, length(y)) + rep(y, each = length(x))
cs <- SS[[1]]
for(i in 2:length(SS)) {
cs <- f(cs, SS[[i]])
}

# Those cs that add up to 221
which ( cs == 221 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Beyond the response from danas above you could use a fast expanding grid 

library(data.table)
# data.table::CJ is a fast expand.grid
# get all value combinations 
DT <- do.call(CJ, args = input_list)  # get all combination



# See link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418479/tracing-the-location-index-of-the-components-of-a-cumulative-sum-of-sequential-l
```

Answer (score 1):

`expand.grid` is your killer. My solution:

```
f <- function(x, y) rep(x, length(y)) + rep(y, each = length(x))
cs <- SS[[1]]
for(i in 2:length(SS)) {
  cs <- f(cs, SS[[i]])
}
```

Comment: I made an EDIT to the question asking if I am able to bak index trace in DF3 and each list every final result that is equal to 221.

Comment: There is an issue on the function you wrote on second thoughts as 1. The first line should be rep = times than the length of the second..... the 2.  The second line result each number should be repeated = times than the length of the third..... and so forth until the last list is added for that first number. Then the second number of the first list should be selected and rep = times than the length of the seond list and so forth as in the first example. This repeats until the last number of the first list is used.