# Tracing the location index of the components of a cumulative sum of sequential lists elements

Tags: r

I have the list below and I would like to trace from the final result from the function at the bottom of the writing the location at each steep of each sublist DF3 that sequentially cumsums to 221. In other words tracing the location index of the components of a cumulative sum of each sequential lists elements.

```
# List

DF3 <- list( c ( 12 ,35 ,90 ,33 ,51 ) , c (  44 , 3 ,88 ,35 ,51 ) , c(12 ,16  ,6 ,10 ,3 ,12 ,2 ,6 ,9 ,4 ,4 ,51 ,13 ,22 ,51 ))

DF3
[[1]]
12 35 90 33 51 
[[2]]
44 3 88 35 51 
[[3]]
12 16 6 10 3 12 2 6 9 4 4 51 13 22 51 

# Obtain the list of elements to add to the prior list of elements sequentially. 

fun <- function (x) tail ( DF3[[x]] , length ( DF3[[x]] ))
S <- lapply ( seq ( length ( DF3 ))[ 1 : ( max (length ( DF3 )))] , fun )[-1]
fun <- function (x) tail (S[[x]] , length( S[[x]])-x)
SS <- c( DF3[[1]][[1]], lapply ( seq ( length ( DF3 )-1), fun ))

SS
[[1]]
12
[[2]]
3 88 35 51 
[[3]]
6 10  3 12  2  6  9  4  4 51 13 22 51

# CumSum of elements  

D1  <-  ( SS[[1]] + SS[[2]] ) 
a   <- seq(nrow(expand.grid(SS[[1]]+SS[[2]],SS[[3]])))
fun <- function (x) sum(expand.grid ( SS[[1]] + SS[[2]] , SS[[3]] )[,1][x], expand.grid ( SS[[1]] + SS[[2]] , SS[[3]] )[,2][x] )
D2  <- unlist(lapply (a , fun))   

# get results 

D1  
D2  

# Those cs that add up to 106
which ( D2 == 106 ) 

# Tracing back the cumsum result from above in DF3

DF3
[[1]]
**12** 35 90 33 51 
[[2]]
44 3 **88** 35 51 
[[3]]
12 16 **6** 10 3 12 2 **6** 9 4 4 51 13 22 51
```

I would like to obtain the index of each list as per DF3 which adds up to the value -- which ( D2 == 106 ) --

```
# Result would be 
DF3[[1]][[1]]
DF3[[2]][[3]]
DF3[[3]][[3]]
```

EDIT 2

The way I am using the fist example is via a list with several sublists, so I do the following. However produces the error at the end of the page as it seems it is not supoorted at present, Would you kinldy let me know how could you find out how would you do it its implementation modus.

```
# problem repeated values.
fun <- function (x) lapply( values[[x]] , function(a) data.table(a,seq_along( a )))
index_map   <- lapply ( seq(length( values )) , fun )
fun <- function(x) lapply ( names ( values[[x]] ), function(b) c(b, sub ( "V" , "index", b )))
nams<- lapply ( seq ( length ( values )) , fun )
fun <- function (x) Map ( setnames , index_map[[x]] , nams[[x]] )
value <-  lapply ( seq ( length ( values )) , fun )
# merge.
for ( index in index_map )
fun  <- function (x) merge ( values[[x]] , index , by = names(index[[x]])    [1])
value  <- lapply (  seq ( length ( values )) , fun )
value
# Error in setkeyv(copy(y), by) : 
Column 'V1' is type 'list' which is not supported as a key column type, currently.
```

Comment: I am not clear about what you are trying to achieve.  Can you make your example list smaller and provide the outcome you want to get?

Comment: @Kota Mori,  I have re writen the question with a simpler example where it is shown how to do this in a pictografic way,

Comment: @Kota Mori - I made a second EDIT as in the implementaion I use a list of sublists, however can not manage to do this as per the method is not implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is the following.
You have a list of vectors (`Df3`) and target value (`106`).  You want to pick a number from each of the vectors in the list so that they add up to the target value.  And you also want the location of the numbers, not only the numbers themselves.

If my interpretation is wrong, please clarify.
Assuming I got it right, I suggest two approaches.

## Define Inputs

Let me define the `input_list` and `total_value` for the clarity of exposition.
`input_list` is identical to `DF3`.

```
input_list <- list(
  c(12, 35, 90, 33, 51),  
  c(44, 3, 88, 35, 51), 
  c(12, 16, 6, 10, 3, 12, 2, 6, 9, 4, 4, 51, 13, 22, 51))
total_value <- 106
```

## Method1

First approach is to use `data.table` package to test all combinations.  Thanks to the efficient implementation of the package, this works faster than `expand.grid`.

```
library(data.table)
# data.table::CJ is a fast expand.grid
# get all value combinations that add up to the target
DT <- do.call(CJ, args = input_list)  # get all combination
values <- unique(DT[rowSums(DT) == total_value])

# make a mapping from value to index
# for each element in the original list
# then rename so that merge works
index_map <- lapply(input_list, function(a)
  data.table(a, seq_along(a)))
nams <- lapply(names(values), function(b)
  c(b, sub("V", "index", b)))
Map(setnames, index_map, nams)

# merge
for (index in index_map)
  values <- merge(values, index, by = names(index)[1])
values
#   V3 V2 V1 index1 index2 index3
#1:  4 51 51      5      5     10
#2:  4 51 51      5      5     11
#3:  6 88 12      1      3      3
#4:  6 88 12      1      3      8
#5: 13  3 90      3      2     13
#6: 22 51 33      4      5     14
```

## Method2

Alternatively, you can find the numbers and indices by the recursive functions.
First, this function finds all combinations of numbers.

```
library(magrittr)
find_comb <- function(input, value, comb = numeric(0)) {
  if (length(input)==1) {
    if (value %in% input[[1]]) {
      c(comb, value)
    } 
  } else {
    lapply(unique(input[[1]]), function(x)
      find_comb(input[-1], value-x, c(comb, x)))
  }
}

find_comb(input_list, total_value) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  matrix(ncol = length(input_list), byrow = TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   12   88    6
#[2,]   90    3   13
#[3,]   33   51   22
#[4,]   51   51    4
```

The function below finds all combinations of indices.

```
find_index <- function(input, value, index = numeric(0)) {
  if (length(input)==1) {
    if (value %in% input[[1]]) {
      lapply(which(input[[1]] == value), 
             function(x) c(index, x))
    } 
  } else {
    lapply(seq_along(input[[1]]), function(i)
      find_index(input[-1], value-input[[1]][i], c(index, i)))
  }
}

find_index(input_list, total_value) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  matrix(ncol = length(input_list), byrow = TRUE)   
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    3    3
#[2,]    1    3    8
#[3,]    3    2   13
#[4,]    4    5   14
#[5,]    5    5   10
#[6,]    5    5   11
```

Comment: My reasoning when framing the problems was unacurate and incomplete appologies as I failed to understand the overall objective and thus design the functions arround it. Many thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: Small caveat the combn function should only include one number per each list. So posible combn are the first element of first list with one of the  elements of the second list and then one element from the third list and soforth. This order is repeated for all elements of each of the lists. check in SS for all elements to be added one of each list

Comment: I made a second EDIT as in the implementaion I use a list of sublists, however can not manage to do this as per the method is not implemented.

Comment: Where in the script did you get error?  and provide data so the errors are reproducible at others' environment.  You can do this by pasting the result of `dput(values)`.

Comment: No I dont get an error, As the example is only for a list and I have to work with a list of lists I did put all the first explanation to work as a series of functions, however whe I have to merge the data of the two sets I get an error as per in for (index in index_map) is not suported at present as a function and  I was wondering if you may know how would this work as a function as to merge the index and the values as in the result of your example, however implemente for lists of lists not just lists. This is found in EDIT 2